# Python Random number guesser problem with loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, random, input

I have built a random number guessing game for practice, but I am having some trouble with the final steps. When outputted, the game works as expected, however, I want it to ask the user if they want to play again after every guessing turn, with 'yes' meaning the game keeps going and 'exit' meaning the game stops. As of now, the game asks the user to guess the number, tells user if said number does not match, and then asks if they want to play, then it just repeats the guessing part, without asking if the user wants to play again. This is not what I want, as I would like to know how to properly write this code.
Here is my program:

```
    import random

    guess = int(input("Guess the number => "))
    rand = random.randrange(1,10)
    print("The number was", rand)
    def guess_rand(guess, rand):
        if rand == guess:
            print("You have guessed right!")
        elif rand > guess:
            print("You guessed too low!")
        elif guess > rand:
            print("You guessed too high!")
    
    guess_rand(guess, rand)

    again = input("Would you like to try again? => ")
    while again.lower() == 'yes':
        guess = int(input("Guess the number => "))
        rand = random.randrange(1,10)
        print("The number was", rand)
        guess_rand(guess, rand)
        if again.lower() == 'exit':
          break
```

Also, if there are any tips on how to keep track of how many guesses the user has taken, and when the game ends, to print them out, I would appreciate that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the statement to take user input again in the `while` loop:

```
again = input("Would you like to try again? => ")
while again.lower() == 'yes':
    guess = int(input("Guess the number => "))
    rand = random.randrange(1,10)
    print("The number was", rand)
    guess_rand(guess, rand)
    again = input("Would you like to try again? => ")
    if again.lower() == 'exit':
    break
```

For keeping the count, you can add a new variable and increment in the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to complete both problems I had.

Comment: Awesome @FranPY3, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you asked and i also added turns to track the player

```
import random
turns = 0
def quit():
    i = input ("Do you want to play again? if yes enter Yes if not Enter No\n")
    if (i.lower() not in ["yes","no"]):
        print ("Invalid input")
        return True
    if (i.lower() == "yes"):
        print ("You choose to play")
        return False
    else:
        print ("Thankyou for playing")
        return True
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess the number => "))
    rand = random.randrange(1,10)
    print("The number was", rand)
    def guess_rand(guess, rand):
        if rand == guess:
            print("You have guessed right!")
        elif rand > guess:
            print("You guessed too low!")
        elif guess > rand:
            print("You guessed too high!")
    
    guess_rand(guess, rand)
    
    if quit():
        print("You have used",turns,"trun(s)")
        break
    else:
        turns += 1
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

**I just added the "again" line of code in while loop and added an else statement**

```
import random

guess = int(input("Guess the number => "))
rand = random.randrange(1,10)
print("The number was", rand)
def guess_rand(guess, rand):
    if rand == guess:
        print("You have guessed right!")
    elif rand > guess:
        print("You guessed too low!")
    elif guess > rand:
        print("You guessed too high!")

guess_rand(guess, rand)

again = input("Would you like to try again? => ")
while again.lower() == 'yes':
    guess = int(input("Guess the number => "))
    rand = random.randrange(1,10)
    print("The number was", rand)
    guess_rand(guess, rand)
    
    again = input("Would you like to try again? => ")
    if again.lower() == 'exit':
      break
    else:
        continue
```